# WPF DataTemplate using same DataContext like parent control

Tags: wpf, viewmodel, datatemplate, datacontext

I am getting crazy about a DataContext problem in WPF. I read the comments here in StackOverflow, but I can't fixed it.

I have the following data template :

```
<DataTemplate  x:Key="TodoTemplate"  >
    <Grid Margin="5 10 10 5" >

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" MaxWidth="30"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" MaxWidth="30"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" MaxWidth="30"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=View}">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <Label Margin="30 0 0 0" Background="LightBlue">View Item</Label>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
```

and a Listbox where I want to reuse my template :

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" Margin="10" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource categoryItemSelector}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentItem,Mode=TwoWay}" MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick"  >

    </ListBox>
```

The Listbox code is embedded in a page and this page sets an DataContext for a view model instance.

```
  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},Path=CategoryDetails}">
```

I've learned that the context menu is not part of the visual tree and the data context cannot be reused directly. The problem is, that I also have a MemoTemplate with the same context menu and I want to reuse my view model here. Can anyone givie me a hint to solve it?

I tried to use the ContextService parameter and also to set a proxy. But my View command is not called via the context menu.

How cam I reuse my view model instance from my page ( via the listbox ) here ?

Thanks in advance
Björn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference the `DataContext` fine even from a `ContextMenu`. Just got to use `PlacementTarget` to route your `Binding`'s.

Not sure where you have this `View` command declared so I'll describe both methods.

**1:** `View` command belongs to the `ItemSource` type `T` of the `ListBox` (In other words, it's in the class that forms the child elements of the `ListBox`)

Pretty simple we set the `DataContext` of the `ContextMenu` same as it's `PlacementTarget` which is the `Grid`.

```
...
<Grid.ContextMenu>
  <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}">
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=View}">
      <MenuItem.Header>
    ...
```

**2:** If `View` command is in the VM `CategoryDetails` as a sibling of `Items` property.

With this approach, We set the `DataContext` of the `ListBox` which is the `CategoryDetails` VM as the `Tag` of the `Grid` element which `ContextMenu` attaches to. Now inside the `ContextMenu` we bind the `MenuItem.Command` to the `ContextMenu`'s `PlacementTarget.Tag.View`

```
...
<Grid Margin="5 10 10 5"
              Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                           AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},
                            Path=DataContext}">
          <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
              <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.View, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}">
...
```

You can substitute `Tag` with an Attached Property if you do not want to use `Tag` for this.

Comment: I see, the trick is to bind to an attached property ( like tag) from my listbox and then again from my menu item to the context menu.